# Apple Export Compliance when using Libsodium and SSL (HTTPS)

Tags: encryption, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Apple's explanation of the export compliance is rather difficult to understand and a complete mix of IT and Law-Knowledge making it difficult to connect to the correct people.

Our app uses:

- Libsodium (using a flutter library, so not apple-default-encryption but open source)
- Https/SSL/... which [require no uploads to app store connect](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devc3f64248f).

I couldn't find out if Libsodium is
*- is accepted by international standard bodies (such as IEEE, IETF, or ITU)*

Other Stackoverflow-Questions ("duplicates") do either not contain explicit Open-Source-Software or are missing helpful answers.